# How to use keras layers in custom keras layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to write my own keras layer. In this layer, I want to use some other keras layers. Is there any way to do something like this:

```
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.num_outputs)

  def call(self, input):
    return self.fc(input)

layer = MyDenseLayer(10)
```

When I do something like

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (16,))
output = MyDenseLayer(10)(input)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = [input], outputs = [output])
model.summary()
```

it outputs 
[image]

How do I make weiths in the dense there trainable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much more comfortable and concise to put existing layers in the tf.keras.models.Model class. If you define non-custom layers such as layers, conv2d, the parameters of those layers are not trainable by default.

```
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs
    self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_outputs)

  def call(self, input):
    return self.fc(input)

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    shape = tf.TensorShape(input_shape).as_list()
    shape[-1] = self.num_outputs
    return tf.TensorShape(shape)

layer = MyDenseLayer(10)
```

Check this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#model_subclassing

Answer (score 18):

If you look at the documentation for how to add custom layers, they recommend that you use the `.add_weight(...)` method. This method internally places all weights in `self._trainable_weights`. So to do what you want, you mush first define the keras layers you want to use, build them, copy the weights and then build your own layer. If I update your code it should be something like

```
class mylayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs, num_outputs2):
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        super(mylayer, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.num_outputs)
        self.fc.build(input_shape)
        self._trainable_weights = self.fc.trainable_weights
        super(mylayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, input):
        return self.fc(input)

layer = mylayer(10)
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(16, ))
output = layer(input)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
model.summary()
```

You should then get what you want
[image]

Comment: Thanks Nicki Skafte. I wasn't quite sure what `build` is for. I looked into the github code, it seems build's main purpose is to set build to True, and in Dense layer's case it also add weights for you. However I don't quite get why we need to set build to True, what's the purpose? Than you~

Comment: The main reason is that all layers need to be build, before you can call model.compile(...). See this [file](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L103-L109).

Comment: `num_outputs2` should be deleted from the `__init__` for the code to run

Comment: how should I do if I use multiple keras layers in `build` ? How to add their trainable weights in to layer's `self._trainable_weights` ? Passing a list of that is not applicable.

Comment: @JunjieChen, do you have solution for your question?

Comment: just solve it. If anyone is looking for the answer: output of `self.fc.trainable_weights` is a list, so if you have 2 trainable layers, you should write like this:
`self.trainable_weights = [self.fc1.trainable_weights[0], self.fc1.trainable_weights[1], self.fc2.trainable_weights[0], self.fc2.trainable_weights[1]]`

Comment: If they are lists, just add the lists together: `self._trainable_weights = self.fc1.trainable_weights + self.fc2.trainable_weights` or use [`extend`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm) method of list

Answer (score 3):

In the [TF2 custom layer Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#layers_are_recursively_composable), they "recommend creating such sublayers in the `__init__` method (since the sublayers will typically have a `build` method, they will be built when the outer layer gets built)." So just move the creation of `self.fc` into `__init__` will give what you want.

```
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs
    self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.num_outputs)

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.built = True

  def call(self, input):
    return self.fc(input)

input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (16,))
output = MyDenseLayer(10)(input)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = [input], outputs = [output])
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 16)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
my_dense_layer_2 (MyDenseLay (None, 10)                170       
=================================================================
Total params: 170
Trainable params: 170
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: I think in this simple case where `build` adds no functionality, you don't need to define the function for your class. If you do add functionality, then it's recommended to call `super(MyDenseLayer, self).build(input_shape)` at the end of your `build` function definition: https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

Comment: @adamconkey, if `super` is `tf.keras.layers.Layer`, calling `super(MyDenseLayer, self).build(input_shape)` is equivalent to `self.built = True`. If `super` is a more complex layer, depending on what part of the base layer you want to inherit, you may need to check the implementation of the `super().build()`, extract the part you really wanted for the derived layer, add new stuff, and call `self.built = True` at the end of `build`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and is clean, concise, and readable.

```
import tensorflow as tf


class MyDense(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyDense, self).__init__(kwargs)
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, tf.keras.activations.relu)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        return self.dense(inputs)


inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=10)
outputs = MyDense(trainable=True)(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='test')
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "test"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
my_dense (MyDense)           (None, 2)                 22        
=================================================================
Total params: 22
Trainable params: 22
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Note that `trainable=True` is needed. I have posted a questions about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475110/are-keras-custom-layer-parameters-non-trainable-by-default/65530670#65530670).