# Are Keras custom layer parameters non-trainable by default?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I built a simple custom layer in Keras and was surprised to find that the parameters were not set to trainable by default. I can get it to work by explicitly setting the trainable attribute. I can't explain why this is by looking at documentation or code. Is this how it is supposed to be or I am doing something wrong which is making the parameters non-trainable by default?
Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf


class MyDense(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyDense, self).__init__(kwargs)
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, tf.keras.activations.relu)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        return self.dense(inputs)


inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=10)
outputs = MyDense()(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='test')
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "test"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
my_dense (MyDense)           (None, 2)                 22        
=================================================================
Total params: 22
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 22
_________________________________________________________________
```

If I change the custom layer creation like this:

```
outputs = MyDense(trainable=True)(inputs)
```

the output is what I expect (all parameters are trainable):

```
=================================================================
Total params: 22
Trainable params: 22
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

then it works as expected and makes all the parameters trainable. I don't understand why that is needed though.

Comment: What's the difference? Setting `trainable=True` doesn't change the number of parameters for me

Comment: Edited to clarify. Doesn't change the number of parameters but changes the parameters from non-trainable to trainable. That's what I am asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No doubt, that's an interesting quirk.

When making a custom layer, a `tf.Variable` will be automatically included in the list of `trainable_variable`. You didn't use `tf.Variable`, but a `tf.keras.layers.Dense` object instead, which will not be treated as a `tf.Variable`, and not set `trainable=True` by default. However, the `Dense` object you used will be set to trainable. See:

```
MyDense().dense.trainable
```

```
True
```

If you used `tf.Variable` (as it should), it will be trainable by default.

```
import tensorflow as tf


class MyDense(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=2, input_dim=10):
        super(MyDense, self).__init__()
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units), dtype="float32"),
            trainable=True,
        )
        b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
        self.b = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=b_init(shape=(units,), dtype="float32"), trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b


inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=10)
outputs = MyDense()(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='test')
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "test"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_11 (InputLayer)        [(None, 10)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
my_dense_18 (MyDense)        (None, 2)                 22        
=================================================================
Total params: 22
Trainable params: 22
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Makes sense though I would prefer to reuse predefined Keras layers as building blocks rather than re-implementing them with tf.Variable. I came across this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475110/are-keras-custom-layer-parameters-non-trainable-by-default/65530670#65530670) which is related.